# Graphite or multiple query with AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, highcharts, graphite

In general I want to know the possible benefits of Graphite. For now I have a web app that receives data directly from JavaScript Ajax call and plots the data using high chart.

1. It first run 20 different queries for each graph using Python from my SQL database.
2. And sends each result data to HighChart library using GET Ajax call.
3. And HighChart adds plot to each graph in realtime.

There is no need to save data because I need only realtime plotting within certain time range. Data outside time range just plushes.

But when I see the 20 Ajax calls in one page I feel like I am doing this in an inefficient way although it gets the job done.

So I looked at the Graphite but it is hard for me to decide which is better. Since I will pull up all data from present SQL table I don't need another storage. But everybody says graphite performs fast but I would still need to instantiate 20 different graphite graphs. Please give me some guidance.

What would you do if you have to visualize 20 different realtime graphs in one page concurrently each of which receives its own query data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe better is call one ajax which gets all data and then prepare parser which will return data for each chart.